# One-liner for nearly redundant list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Consider two list comprehensions `gamma` and `delta` with nearly redundant code. The difference being the sliced lists `alpha` and `beta`, namely

```
gamma = [alpha[i:i+30] for i in range(0,49980,30)]
delta = [beta[i:i+30] for i in range(0,49980,30)]
```

Is there a pythonic way to write this as a one liner (say `gamma,delta = ...` )?

I have a few other pieces of code that are similar in nature, and I'd like to simplify the code's seeming redundancy.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Just commented the same thing on coldspeed's answer

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Didn't notice that OP wanted 2D lists.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: Double zip? `gamma, delta = zip(values[i:i+30] for i in range(0,50000,30) for values in [list(zip(alpha, beta))])`

Comment: @sunspots: did you consider using `numpy` with `reshape`?

Comment: @Daniel I hadn't, could you say more? I eventually want to `vstack` these chunks.

Comment: with `alpha = np.array(alpha)` you can write `gamma = alpha.reshape(30, -1)`.

Comment: @sunspots Hmm, if you had tagged this numpy, you'd have had your answer marked duplicate, because reshape is a common idiom ;-)

Comment: @Daniel 30 doesn't divide 50000.

Comment: @PaulPanzer terrific point (I'll edit this). I'd been using 49980. Cheers.

Comment: Btw. is there anything wrong with `gamma, delta = ([x[i:i+30] for i in range(0,49980,30)] for x in (alpha, beta))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as your question related to combining both the *list comprehension* expression above is concerned, you can get `gamma` and `delta` by using [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with single *list comprehension* as:

```
gamma, delta = zip(*[(alpha[i:i+30], beta[i:i+30]) for i in range(0,50000,30)])
```

---

Sample example to show how `zip` works:

```
>>> zip(*[(i, i+1) for i in range(0, 10, 2)])
[(0, 2, 4, 6, 8), (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)]
```

Here our *list comprehension* will return the list of tuples:

```
>>> [(i, i+1) for i in range(0, 10, 2)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
```

Then we are unpacking this list using `*` and using zip we are aggregating the element from each of the iterables:

```
>>> zip(*[(i, i+1) for i in range(0, 10, 2)])
[(0, 2, 4, 6, 8), (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)]
```

---

As an alternative, for dividing the list into evenly sized chunks, please take a look at [*"How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/2063361)

Comment: @Daniel how does this compromise readability? And are you referring to the slicing or the latter zip?

Comment: @Daniel Performance wise usage of `zip` in above example will performa better as compared to the two *list comprehensions*

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Have you tested that? The separate comprehensions are faster on my machine.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: your zip-variant is about 50% slower than two LCs.

Comment: The result isn't quite right, since you produce tuples instead of lists.

Answer (score 8):

Although one-line `list-comprehensions` are really useful, they aren't always the best choice. So here since you're doing the same chunking to both `lists`, if you wanted to change the chunking, you would have to modify both lines.

Instead, we could use a `function` that would chunk any given `list` and then use a one-line assignment to chunk `gamma` and `delta`.

```
def chunk(l):
    return [l[i:i+30] for i in range(0, len(l), 30)]

gamma, delta = chunk(gamma), chunk(delta)
```

Comment: More directly, if you want to reuse them, put them in a function.

Comment: I prefer this: `def chunk(l, size):
    return [l[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(l), size)]`

Comment: @RoadRunner Yeah I was considering whether or not to make it general purpose, could go either way **:)**

Comment: Yeah not that important for this question, I still upvoted regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way...

```
gamma, delta = ([src[i:i+30] for i in range(0,49980,30)] for src in (alpha, beta))
```

It's a bit faster than the accepted zip solution:

```
genny 3.439506340350704
zippy 4.3039169818228515
```

Code:

```
from timeit import timeit
alpha = list(range(60000))
beta = list(range(60000))
def genny():
    gamma, delta = ([src[i:i+30] for i in range(0,49980,30)] for src in (alpha, beta))
def zippy():
    gamma, delta = zip(*[(alpha[i:i+30], beta[i:i+30]) for i in range(0,50000,30)])
n = 1000
print('genny', timeit(genny, number=n))
print('zippy', timeit(zippy, number=n))
```

Comment: This is what Paul Panzer put in the comments and Peter Wood had a similar idea with zip (earlier in the comments).

Comment: I hadn't seen the timing portion before, it's a nice addition.

Answer (score 0):

You can you lambda expression:

```
g = lambda l: [l[i:i+30] for i in range(0,50000, 30)]
gamma, delta = g(alpha), g(beta)
```

Comment: If you're naming a lambda, then there's no point to it being a lambda.

Comment: Please do _not_ use `lambda` for named functions.  `lambda` is supposed to be for anonymous functions. If you want a named function, use the `def` syntax. However, I do agree that it's probably a good idea to use a function for this task.

Comment: I agree with the comments and I also think that using a function is a better idea for this. It is difficult sometimes to say which is a more pythonic solution. But this seems to be a legit use case for function.

Comment: I've seen in lots of places that this a legit way to define a one-liner function... why is this wrong?

Comment: It's not technically wrong, it's just bad style. It only saves a couple of bytes of typing, so what's the benefit of using a `lambda` instead of a proper named function?

Comment: @PM2Ring Gotcha

Comment: All functions have a `__name__` attribute. This can be handy when debugging, among other situations. (So if you print a function, or convert it to a string, the name attribute is part of that string representation). But a lambda's name is set to `'<lambda>'`, which isn't very informative. ;)